# Can you improve Python's functions?

Tags: python

I've been thinking about few functions in Python for a while, and been able to define functions that replace their duties. My question is, are default functions the most efficient, or should I attempt to build more efficient ones.

I've re-done `list.reverse()` for example,

```py
def reverse(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
        lst.append(lst.pop(i))
```

And this method works. The list is sorted. But is it any better than `list.reverse()` in terms of efficiency or memory used?

Comment: You can time them and see how they stack up.

Comment: That's probably a lot slower than `list.reverse()`.

Comment: Some of the functions in Python are implemented in C. If you reimplement it, it is very unlikely you are going to improve it unless the fundamental computational complexity is reduced, e.g., from O(n) to O(log N).

Comment: You can use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) module to compare runtimes.  But be aware that most builtin functions and methods are implemented in C, and have undergone many iterations of improvement and optimisation.

Comment: Many builtins are written in C code which means writing your own Python version probably will be slower than its C equivalent.

Comment: It's always good idea use language build-in methods and functions. They are optimized in most cases. Generate very big list, and make time monitoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timed—yours is slower by an order of magnitude:

```py
import time

def reverse(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
        lst.append(lst.pop(i))

thelist = ["Hello World","Something","Element"]

start = time.time()
for x in range(0,1000000):
    reverse(thelist)
print(f"Yours: {time.time()-start}")

start = time.time()
for x in range(0,1000000):
    thelist.reverse()
print(f"Theirs: {time.time()-start}")
```

Output:

```
Yours: 1.0335352420806885
Theirs: 0.11595964431762695
```

Unfortunately, yours is actually a great deal slower, and I don't think this will improve over long computations.

--

**Edit:**

If we compare @Alec_Alameddine's solution to yours and Python's, we get this:

```
Yours: 1.5206882953643799
Alec's: 0.41818690299987793
Theirs: 0.20143365859985352
```

While Alec's is *significantly* faster than your's, Python's is about twice as fast. So stick with the built-in functions!

Answer (score 3):

`reverse()` is implemented in C, which is significantly faster than your implementation. Most python functions are designed very intelligently and are the most efficient they can possibly be in order to maintain their desired functionality. If you'd like to contribute, you can go to the CPython [github page](https://github.com/python/cpython) and attempt to better some of the code.

```
PyList_Reverse(PyObject *v)
{
    PyListObject *self = (PyListObject *)v;

    if (v == NULL || !PyList_Check(v)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    if (Py_SIZE(self) > 1)
        reverse_slice(self->ob_item, self->ob_item + Py_SIZE(self));
    return 0;
```

FYI: A much easier python implementation of `reverse()` is simply slicing

```
def reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]
```